# Using one table for multiple arguments

Tags: graphics

So I want to plot two graphs (on the same plot). One which is the $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n x_i}{n}$ and the other $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n x_i}{n-1}$ where x is a set created by `RandomInteger[{a,b},n]` and then have n slowly increase. I was wondering if this would be a sort of nice convergence plot over a large interval. The problem is as seen I want all of them to use the one {n,c,d} table for their iteration but Sum wants a copy, Plot wants a copy and RandomInteger wants the length of it. How can I use one of it for all of those?

Comment: They will converge to (a+b)/2 ... or am I missing something?

Comment: p0[a_, b_, 1] := p0[a, b, 1] = RandomInteger[{a, b}]; 
p0[a_, b_, n_] := 
 p0[a, b, n] = (p0[a, b, n - 1] (n - 1) + RandomInteger[{a, b}])/n;
p1[a_, b_, n_] := p0[a, b, n] n/(n - 1);
ListLinePlot[{Table[p0[0, 10, k], {k, 2, 50000}], 
  Table[p1[0, 10, k], {k, 2, 50000}]}]

Answer (score 3):

Adding an additional (optional) parameter for increment, define

```
 datalistPlot[a_Integer, b_Integer, c_Integer, d_Integer, e_Integer: 1] := 
 Module[{left = Mean@RandomInteger[{a, b}, c]},{
 Transpose@
 Table[{left=(n - 1) left/n + RandomInteger[{a, b}]/n, n left/(n - 1)}, {n, c, d, e}], 
 {c, d}, 
 (a + b)/2
 }] 
 // ListLinePlot[#[[1]], 
 GridLines -> {None, {{#[[3]], Directive[Red, Thick]}}}, 
 DataRange -> #[[2]], PlotRange -> {Automatic, #[[3]] + {-1, 1}}] &
```

and use as

```
datalistPlot[list[0, 10, 10, 500, 10]
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want each of the summations over two different randomly generated lists:

```
{Total@ RandomInteger[{a, b}, #]/#, 
     Total@ RandomInteger[{a, b}, #]/(# - 1)} & /@ Range[2, n] // 
  Transpose // ListLinePlot
```

Comment: `Total[]` might be a useful thing here.

Comment: @J.M. Yes you are right... some pre version 5 habits showing up here :)

Comment: Don't worry; you aren't alone. I haven't fully shaken off old *Mathematica* habits of mine as well...

Comment: Is there any advantage of `Total` over `Plus@@`?

Comment: Some cursory experiments seem to suggest Total is probably faster.